# Will my married life suffer or my husband die because of this wish?

Tags: allah

I am 27 years old and married for 3 months.Before my marriage I made a Dua to Allah that my husband should have sex for the first and last time with me.I meant I should be the one for him no one else. But now I'm kinda afraid that something might happen to him because of my wish. Because I used the phrase "first and last time" in my wish. This question might seem a bit stupid to you but I am afraid what if something happens to him as I love him dearly and only long for him. Will he die because of this please answer......

Comment: Allah knows what is in your heart better than anyone. Heck even yourself. So when u made ure dua, Allah understood what u meant and will acknowledge your prayers. Certainly, ure heart doesn't want ure man to die so I don't think u have anything to worry about.

Comment: Allah knows what inside you (and your mind) better than enybody!

Answer (score 1):

Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah),(Bukhari)
So your intention were clear so relax.
Sura 67 - Ayat 13

وَأَسِرُّواْ قَوْلَكُمْ أَوِ ٱجْهَرُواْ بِهِۦٓ‌ۖ إِنَّهُۥ عَلِيمُۢ بِذَاتِ ٱلصُّدُورِ

And conceal your speech or publicize it; indeed, He is Knowing of that within the breasts.

Islam: The Noble Quran (https://goo.gl/prmwod)
Allah is all aware of everyone action and intention.